# Is it correct to post a question more than one Stack Exchange site?

Tags: support, cross-posting

I asked [a question related to SQL queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38955385/which-one-is-better-not-exist-data-vs-isnulldata-0/38955504#38955504), and the answerer told me to ask on [dba.stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) for the part of my question relative to performance.

Is it OK if I copy my post and repost it to the second site, prior to some adjustment, i.e. removing the part about good practice?

Comment: Cross posting the same question is frowned upon.  Asking two related but separate questions on two different sites should be fine.

Comment: @NathanOliver So if i update my question it should be just fine.

Comment: @rene Thanks, i was looking for a similar question prior to posting this one and didn't find one. It answers my question as well.